# How to store retry statement in Proc object

Tags: ruby, proc

I am trying to store a block with `retry` statement, but am getting a syntax error: `Invalid retry`. How do I store it right?

```
retries = 3
proc = Proc.new do
  if retries > 0
    p " Retries left: #{retries}"
    retries -= 1
    retry
  end
end
begin
  ...
rescue SomeErrorOne
  proc.call
rescue SomeErrorTwo
  proc.call
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the `retry` to `redo`. I think some changes were made in Ruby 1.9 as the `retry` keyword was abused.

The difference can be found here: http://rubyquicktips.com/post/1122838559/redo-vs-retry See the comment at the bottom.